# AWS EC2 instance sync with S3 files in same AZ - do I pay for GET and PUT?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The documentation is a bit unclear on this - if I'm using aws s3 sync on an ec2 instance to download and upload files from an S3 bucket in the same region as the instance, do I pay for get and put?

Comment: Yes, you would pay all applicable Amazon S3 charges. Traffic between Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3 in the same region does not incur Data Transfer costs.

Answer (score -1):

No, you will not incur any S3 charges as the data transferred from an Amazon S3 bucket to any AWS service(s) within the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket (including to a different account in the same AWS Region) is free of charge.

Check the official [pricing information here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

**UPDATE**

I understood the question was about the data transfer only. My answer is correct since the data transfer is indeed free of charge. However, other standard S3 charges **DO apply**.

```
You pay for requests made against your S3 buckets and 
objects. S3 request costs are based on the request type, and 
are charged on the quantity of requests as listed in the table 
below. When you use the Amazon S3 console to browse your 
storage, you incur charges for GET, LIST, and other requests 
that are made to facilitate browsing. Charges are accrued at the 
same rate as requests that are made using the API/SDK.
```

Best,
Stefan

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - I think these are charged for EC2 from S3:
"PUT, COPY, POST, LIST requests (per 1,000 requests) GET, SELECT, and all other requests (per 1,000 requests)"